# How to frame an array with characters without modifying the array?

Tags: java, arrays, printing

So I have an array of a user specified size. What I need to do is print that array, but have it surrounded by characters on the left and top, as like a frame. Ex:

    `*******
    *1 2 3 
    *1 2 3 
    *1 2 3`

I need to be able to print this and not modify the original array. Is there any way to do this? Like I understand how to print the top portion, but I don't really know how to print the side frame and then print the array "inside" that frame.

Also, I'm still a beginner at java, so go easy on me.

Comment: You are not going to get much love here without showing some effort.  Have you tried to code anything??

Comment: Yes lol. This is one part of a giant project I'm working on. I've just hit a dead end and honestly cannot think how to print the frame around the array.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out, with help from a different post ([Adding a border to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19121535/adding-a-border-to-an-array))

This is my current code

```
for (int x=0; x < userWidth; x++) { 
                    System.out.print("#");
                }
              System.out.println("");
              for (int i=0; i < Array.length; i++){
                    System.out.print("#");
                    System.out.print(Array[i]);
                    System.out.println("");
                }
```

This prints a frame around the left side of the array and the top of the array!